# Recognise which key is pressed in bb

Tags: blackberry, keypress

I am trying to recognise which key is pressed and do the action as required. Basically using them to perform zoom in  n zoom out on the press of "i" n "o".

I have used  these methods:

```
protected boolean keyDown(int keycode, int time)
{           
    int key=Keypad.key(keycode);
    String keyC=Integer.toString(key);
    System.out.println("*********************************   key pressed"+key);
    System.out.println("*********************************   key pressed to string"+keyC);
    return super.keyDown(keycode, time);
}

public boolean keyChar(char key, int status, int time) 
{
    System.out.println("inside keychar");
    boolean retval = false;
    int zoom=mapField.mf.getZoom();
    if(key== 'o'||key== 'O')
    {
        zoom=zoom-3;
        mapField.mf.setZoom(zoom);

        retval = true;
    }
    super.mf.setZoom(zoom);
    return retval;
}
```

these methods dont seem to work at all.

Comment: By don't work do you mean that the two methods are never called or is there some other error you are getting?  Also, could you post the class which this code resides in.  Looking at things like if you are using a KeyListener are important in seeing what is wrong.

Comment: Yeah , they were never getting called. I found the error. It was coz these methods were inside in the inner class, once i put them on the screen directly,it started working.  
  I still need to know how to get the code or char from any key that is pressed. There should be a method ...Something I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

Ok let me give you how I would do it and hopefully there will be an aha moment somewhere.

```
    import net.rim.device.api.system.KeyListener;
    import net.rim.device.api.ui.Keypad;
    // any other imports you might need

    public final class VivartClass implements KeyListener {

    public boolean keyChar(char key, int status, int time) 
        {
            System.out.println("inside keychar");
            if(key== 'o'||key== 'O')
            {
                int zoom=mapField.mf.getZoom();
                zoom=zoom-3;
                mapField.mf.setZoom(zoom);
                super.mf.setZoom(zoom);
                return true;


            }
            return super.keyChar(key, status, time);
       }

       protected boolean keyDown(int keycode, int time) {

            int key=Keypad.key(keycode);
            String keyC=Integer.toString(key);
            System.out.println("*********************************   key pressed"+key);
            System.out.println("*********************************   key pressed to string"+keyC);
            return super.keyDown(keycode, time);
        }

        }
```

**Then in your application constructor**

```
        public Application() {
            addKeyListener(new VivartClass());
            // all your other stuff you may want to do
    }
```

"apps should use the keyChar notification to determine which characters a user has pressed" is the recommendation from www.blackberry.com in their API.

Also, make sure there are no other keyChar methods lying around elsewhere in your code.  If there are, then this one you are expecting to be called will not be called.

Also instead of key=='o' try to use some of the values from net.rim.device.api.system.Characters to see if there are some keys you **can** get for example

```
key == Characters.LATIN_SMALL_LETTER_O
```

Oh, one last try.  You could see if

```
Keypad.getAltedChar(key) == 'o'
```

improves your situation as well.

Sorry I have neither a simulator nor a device in front of me at the moment so I cannot run these with you, but hopefully I have hit on the issue with one of these.